# Encode & play video formats without 3rd party codec packs

Tags: ffmpeg, encode, vlc, codec, handbrake

We have built a windows based software system that allows users to import their own video for viewing in the software. It works fine for AVI and WMV as we use a windows based player. For encoding or playing to work with most common video formats we have to ask our customers to download a 3rd party codec pack, such as K-Lite or Combined Community Codec Pack. Many of our customers are not allowed to do this due to IT Management rules.

Are they are any suggestions regarding a player and encoder that can be built into our windows based software without needing 3rd party codec packs.

I am not sure if ffmpeg, handbrake, VLC can be used for this purpose.

Thanks. J

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest MP4 with H264 + AAC/MP3

This works in any browser without any third party codecs AFAIK.

Give this a try [HTML5 Video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: Thanks I have decided that will be the format. However my question relates to what encoder and player we can use so our customers dont have to download a 3rd party codec. The codec pack download is what we must avoid.

Comment: Now that I've read it carefully I would suggest VLC bindings. If you really want to go with your own software to playback videos just use libVLC. This is easily achieved in Java and in Windows. [Example: VLC dll](https://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll/)